# How can I use TextMessage to send an XML file to the JMS Queue?

Tags: java, xml, jms

The Oracle Docs say -

> A TextMessage object is used to send a message containing a java.lang.String. It inherits >from the Message interface and adds a text message body.
>   This message type can be used to transport text-based messages, including those with XML >content.

How is this possible? Are the contents of the XML only send-able(by converting it into an Object and then sending it)? Can the XML File be really put on the Queue in any way and then be read on the receiver side?

Comment: you can send the xml file as File object or parsed Object(by SAX or etc) or read all xml data as string and send .What you want exactly ?

Comment: I am aware of the second part(read all xml data as string and send). Can you help me with the first one? Or can this be done - writing an XML(or any file) and putting in the Queue and the receiver then reads the XML(file) and process it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use this and object you send must be Serializable

```
class Master implements serializable
 {
   List<File> f=new ArrayList<File>();
  //getter and setter
 }
```

Add --xml files as many as you want

```
     Master eMaster = new Master();
    eMaster.setF();
    //add Files here 

    QueueSender queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queue1);
    ObjectMessage objMessage = queueSession.createObjectMessage();
    objMessage.setObject(eMaster);
    queueSender.send(objMessage);
```

Receiver End :--

```
        Master em =null;
        Message message = queueReceiver.receive(1);
        if (message instanceof ObjectMessage
                && ((ObjectMessage) message).getObject() instanceof Master) {
            em = (Master) ((ObjectMessage) message).getObject();
            //use this and get list of xml file and iterate and process xml file by 
            //below link
        }
```

[1 xml parsing link here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaXML/article.html)

[2 xml parsing link here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152)

Comment: @NihaSharma do you need xml processing logic also ?

Comment: I think i need the XML processing of the receiver too. I tried but nothing seems to happen.

Comment: what will you do with xml file, tell me ? I will do the needful.

Comment: I have to read that XML file. - Message message = receiver.receive(); ObjectMessage objMessage = (ObjectMessage) message; 
The xml corresponds to a "Company" class, so I need to take the values out of the XML and create an object out of it. Hope you understand what I need!