# How to send the xml file and xml string to jms queue?

Tags: java, jms

I need to send the xml as file and also as string to jms queue.

For sending xml as file  on queue

i am planning to go this way [How can I use TextMessage to send an XML file to the JMS Queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264055/how-can-i-use-textmessage-to-send-an-xml-file-to-the-jms-queue)

For sending the xml as string

i am first planning to read xml as string using buffered reader and then send it as text message.

Are these right solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes those are the right solutions.

However, in my opinion, it might be more efficient if you use JSON instead of XML (less data over the network).