# How to Implement a perfect Queue with database

Tags: java, database-design, architecture

I am designing a Shopping Cart ,
I have X Products in my Cart.
Each product is associated with a Shop.

- example product 1 is sold by Shop1
- example product 2 is sold by Shop2
- example product 3 is sold by Shop3
- example product 4 is sold by Shop4

---

1. I get Product1 details (availability and price in Shop1 [when ever a product is sold or price is changed]) in the form of XML
2. I should update these details in my Shopping Cart.

How should this be handled?

I divided the project in 2 parts:

1: **Project 1**

I have created a form based application , this is used by all Shops.
when ever a Product is Sold , the Shop Admin will enter Product Details ( number of units available ...etc ) and submit. i convert this into XML and save into Table1.

Example:
**Table1**

```
Product_ID  | XML 
--------------------------------
Prod_1A     | xml  
Prod_2A     | xml  
Prod_3A     | xml  
Prod_1A     | xml
```

---

2: **Project 2**

In this Project I used

```
ServletContextListener
```

when ever I deploy this project , with the help of  `ServletContextListener contextInitialized` method
I am creating a `Timer`, that will run for every 10 seconds. In that `Timer` I am checking whether **Table1** contains any  records or not. If yes,  in the run method of Timer class I am picking 1 record from it and updating the data in my Shopping cart.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5 ; i++) {

    fetchFromNotif = fetchFromNotif(); // this methods picks a unique record
    if (fetchFromNotif != null) {
        new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                // updating the data in my Shopping cart DB.
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
}
```

My Question is if this the right way of using `Timer` for every 10 seconds and creating many threads? Is there any better way for implement these requirements.

Is there any better approach for implementing a queue mechanism for this type of scenario?

Comment: Are you familiar with Java's ExecutorService? You can use it to setup a queue and process items that are added to the queue in a variety of ways. Here's some documentation from the Spring framework on how it can be used: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Comment: Maybe a better solution is to not duplicate the product details on the cart at all. Just obtain them lazily whenever required. If performance is a concern, develop some API with caching capability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JMS for this.

-You will have JMS service running on server(Can be same server where your project 2 is deployed)

-Project 1- will add XML to queue

-Project 2- will read from the queue.

With JMS you won't have to implement your own timer/listener.
Project 1 will get connection to queue, and will add message to queue. JMS client will implement [MessageListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageListener.html). Whenever, project 1 adds messages to queue, [MessageListener#onMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageListener.html#onMessage%28javax.jms.Message%29) in project 2 will be invoked.

For creating queue, you can use [Apache's ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/).

Also check:
[how-can-i-use-textmessage-to-send-an-xml-file-to-the-jms-queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264055/how-can-i-use-textmessage-to-send-an-xml-file-to-the-jms-queue)

Edit: As pointed out by 'Amrola', using MDB(Message Driven Bean) would be better approach than using Message Listener. Using MDB will provide you with services offered by ejb container.

Comment: use Message Driven Bean (MDB) to read from the Queue instead of listeners .

Answer (score 2):

You could also identify exact situations when is this updated product information needed in the shopping cart and pull the information instead of pushing it. Maybe you don't need to have it updated in real-time?

Maybe you could check if any updates in product inventory or price happened only when user goes to the check-out? Or maybe also at some other point you identify...

That way you could simplify things and not worry about threads or queues.

Answer (score 2):

As I clearly understand, you need to poll *Project #1* module database from *Project #2* to get product updates and change your shopping card data in *Database #2*.

Without going into details, in *Project #2* you could implement ScheduledExecutorService and do fetch and update inside it:

```
public class MyAppServletContextListener 
           implements ServletContextListener {
. . .
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent e) {
        //Schedule cart updater

        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
            .schedule(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ProductUpdate productUpdate = fetchProductUpdate();

                    //do some additional stuff with productUpdate, some checks or logging

                    updateShoppingCart(shoppingCart, productUpdate);
                }
            }, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

}
```

But actually, If not strongly required to separate product update logic from cart updates I recommend to update all cart data in *Project #1* right after product was updated by the shop.
Then you do not need any timers because you already in product update context and you can exactly see which product was updated and what data was changed.

```
public void processProductUpdateForm(ProductUpdate upd) {
    updateProductInDatabase(upd);


    updateAssociatedShoppingCarts(upd);

}
```